# Adding to vocab during Tensorflow seq2seq run

Tags: tensorflow, machine-translation

I am using the Tensorflow seq2seq [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/) to play with machine translation. Say I have trained the model for some time and determine that I want to supplement the original vocab with new words to enhance the quality of the model. Is there a way to pause training, add words to the vocabulary, and then resume training from the most recent checkpoint? I attempted to do so but when I began training again I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "execute.py", line 405, in <module>
train()
File "execute.py", line 127, in train
model = create_model(sess, False)
File "execute.py", line 108, in create_model
model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1388, in restore
{self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign   requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [384633] rhs shape=   [384617]
 [[Node: save/Assign_82 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@proj_b"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](proj_b, save/RestoreV2_82)]]

Caused by op u'save/Assign_82', defined at:
File "execute.py", line 405, in <module>
train()
File "execute.py", line 127, in train
model = create_model(sess, False)
File "execute.py", line 99, in create_model
model = seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel( gConfig['enc_vocab_size'],  gConfig['dec_vocab_size'], _buckets, gConfig['layer_size'], gConfig['num_layers'], gConfig['max_gradient_norm'], gConfig['batch_size'], gConfig['learning_rate'], gConfig['learning_rate_decay_factor'], forward_only=forward_only)
File "/home/jrthom18/data/3x256_bs32/easy_seq2seq/seq2seq_model.py", line 166, in __init__
self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=2.0)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1000, in __init__
self.build()
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1030, in build
restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 624, in build
restore_sequentially, reshape)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 373, in _AddRestoreOps
assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(tensors, shapes))
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 130, in restore
self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/jrthom18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [384633] rhs shape= [384617]
 [[Node: save/Assign_82 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@proj_b"],   use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](proj_b, save/RestoreV2_82)]]
```

Obviously the new vocab is larger and so the tensor sizes do not match. Is there some way around this?

Comment: I think you need to understand how a sequence to sequence model work. You can't simply replace the dictionary that's why it's still an open problem in handling open vocabulary for NMT, take a look at http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/Luong-Cho-Manning-NMT-ACL2016-v4.pdf

Comment: There are talks/thoughts on how to change the dictionary/vocabulary half way during training but there's no proven concrete way yet. Seemingly the state-of-art for an open vocabulary is to do some special "word piece model" or "byte pair encoding" before training. But once the vocabulary is set, you can't swap out the words or add to the list easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update your vocab once its set but you can always use shared wordpiece model. It will help you to directly copy out of vocab words form source to target output.